# what does 'u' flag stand for in most of git commands

Tags: git

`u` flag appears in a lot of git commnads, such as

```
git push -u origin master   // setup remote tracking branch
git add -u  // stages modifications and deletions, without new files
...
```

In each commands, u means sth differenct in different context, but since git choose u as a flag, so what does `u` stand for? Does it stand for a general word such as "unique", "universal"? I mean `-u` = `--u*`? what is `u*`?

Comment: Read `git help push`, `git help add` to find the longer form of the flag. (They’re not related.)

Comment: `-u` is short for something longer, but the longer thing depends on the command: `--update`, `--set-upstream-to`, `--unmerged`, and so on. If you find the short names confusing, consider typing in the longer names instead.

Comment: The general concept of having both long flags (`--thingamabob`) and short ones (`-t` or `-b` might be the shortened form of Thing-a-ma-Bob here) goes back to the GNU project from the 1990s. POSIX had `getopt`, for single letter options, so Gnu had to have `getopt_long` for both.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, those `-u` are not related:

- `git add -u` is introduced with [commit bc3561f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc3561f35991f97adfa2b22a8a5093f19717c71f) with Git v1.5.2-rc3 in May 2007
- `git push -u` is introduced with [commit e9fcd1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9fcd1e2121100d43d2d212eb6c6f1fc82aade1d) with Git v1.7.0-rc0, Jan. 2010

In the first case, the [add -u discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/dbfc82860704200418o4d27b5a6pc3ea2f5abe25be8e@mail.gmail.com/T/#u) was (Apr. 2007):

> I picked "`-u`" instead of "`-a`" because I wanted to stress that this is about "*updating*" (which has connotation that it is relative to something, and in this case it is relative to the current "index"), and not about "`all`", which "`-a`" would imply.

There was no objection to `-u` in the second case ([discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/1263595630-18962-1-git-send-email-ilari.liusvaara@elisanet.fi/T/#u)), since it was about *upstream*.